# What are these cards used for in cooperative mode?

Tags: nemesis

What is the use of the "Interruption" card in cooperative mode, or for the Captain's "Log Key" item and "Command" cards. The command can, maybe, be used as a free move for someone, but I don't think the "Log key" has any use, whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

If there's no other use for the interruption card in co-op mode, you can still use it to pay for another action that requires a discard.

Also, don't forget that Nemesis can be played either co-op or SEMI-co-op, where the Interrupts can have their originally intended effects.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Agreed. Cards are still resources that can pay for other discard costs, even if the effect on the card itself isn't helpful.